# How can I install django-stdimage in my django project, rather than as a module (jailed shell, no path access)

Tags: python, django, module, dreamhost

The question about covers it. I'm using dreamhost, and need to utilize the stdimagefield rather than image field so I can do this:

```
 image3 = StdImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', size=(640, 480))
```

If there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Edit: Trying it like this, everything is working with the "python manage.py shell" as you can see below:

```
>>> from stdimage import StdImageField
>>> image = StdImageField(upload_to='path', size=(425,325))
>>> print image
<stdimage.fields.StdImageField object at 0x762db3ac5910>
```

When I try to use it in my model though, I get this error on every page:

Using the URLconf defined in runningshoesreview.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

1. ^admin/(.*)
2. ^reviews/

The current URL, internal_error.html, didn't match any of these.

Comment: lol, I suppose a better way of installing stdimage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the module contents into your project, making it a package if necessary. I put "external" modules in an `external` package.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the `django-stdimage` folder into your project folder (it should already be a package).

Comment: I put it into the folder, added "stdimage" to my installed apps. Then i put 'from stdimage import StdImageField' and the page didn't even load. It said "

Using the URLconf defined in runningshoesreview.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

   1. ^admin/(.*)
   2. ^reviews/

The current URL, internal_error.html, didn't match any of these.
"

Any idea why?

Comment: @Codygman: Well something is not working, I guess you have `debug=False` in your `settings.py`. To know what is the problem you have set it to `True`.

Comment: No I had it set to False. Odd that it's trying to load the internal error template. Here is a link for you to look at it, i'll leave it as it is overnight:
http://dev.runningshoesreview.org/reviews/K-swiss-ariake-review/